# Simplified Querying on Normalized Data for Composite Output

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, activerecord, database-normalization

On a Rails 3 application we have a highly normalized database schema, which is necessary for multiple reasons.  Additionally, we need to provide some read-only RESTful routes whose virtual resources are derived from the "combined" (denormalized) data from several models and we must present the results as a JSON document.

For example, we would have models like State, City, and Neighborhood, each with their own data and associations.  The "RESTful resource" is the Neighborhood but we always want to include the name of the associated State and City.  So a "GET" request to the URI "`/neighborhood/nm/albuquerque`" would return a JSON array of all the neighborhoods in Albuquerque, NM, for example:

```javascript
[{"state":"NM","city":"Albuquerque","neighborhood":"North Valley"},
 {"state":"NM","city":"Albuquerque","neighborhood":"Northeast Heights"}, //... ]
```

However, omitting the city name in the URI ("`GET /neighborhood/nm`") would return a list of all the neighborhoods in all of the cities in New Mexico.

**What is the Rails 3 preferred approach to generating the database query in this situation?**

The most direct approach I can imagine is to generate a custom SQL query which selects the necessary data from the database and returns the resulting records as JSON, without performing any ActiveRecord object deserialization (since we just need raw data with no processing), for example:

```ruby
def neighborhood # our Action in the target Controller...
  state, city, hood = params[:state], params[:city], params[:hood]
  query = <<-__HERE__
    SELECT s.name AS state, c.name AS city, n.name AS neighborhood
    FROM states AS s, cities AS c, neighborhoods AS n
    WHERE n.city_id=c.id AND c.state_id=s.id
  __HERE__
  query += ' AND s.slug=' + ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(state) if state
  query += ' AND c.slug=' + ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(city) if city
  query += ' AND n.slug=' + ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(hood) if hood
  query += ' ORDER BY state, city, neighborhood ASC'
  render :json => ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query)
end
```

This solution is conceptually straightforward and relies on the database for the heavy lifting but feels distinctly un-Rails-ish.  I've tried achieving the same effect using a combination of Arel/AR queries and "as_json" overrides but I can't seem to get it right (and efficient) after some time and frustration.

Am I missing something big, new, and cool in Rails 3 or is this just a situation where the quick-and-dirty solution is the right way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a json builder.  A couple of railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl

http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder

Doing straight sql is a bit un-rails-ish.  If you don't need the performance, basic queries would be easier to populate some variables, and then use the builder to craft the json.

It's *not* the most efficient way performance wise, but that usually is not the goal of rails... development speed and maintenance is.

If you have a performance problem, use a profiler to find the problem before "solving" it!

**edit** 
As for the query, you can use joins and includes.  I'm assuming state has_many cities, city has_many neighborhoods.

```
query = Neighborhood.includes(:city => :state)
query = query.order('states.name, cities.name, neighborhoods.name ASC')
query = query.where("cities.name =?", params[:city]) if params[:city]
query = query.where("neighborhoods.name =?", params[:hood]) if params[:hood]
query = query.where("states.name =?", params[:state]) if params[:state]
```

From there you can build your json data...

```
query.each do |hood|
  # code to build json row using:   hood.name, hood.city.name, and hood.city.state.name
end
```

Better yet, define some methods to help:

```
class Neighborhood ...
  def city_name
    city ? city.name : "No city"
  end

  def state_name
    (city && city.state) ? city.state.name : "No state"
  end
end
```

With that in place, I see now that a builder is overkill.  Just map an array of hashes, and call to_json:

```
query = Neighborhood.includes(:city => :state)
query = query.order('states.name, cities.name, neighborhoods.name ASC')
query = query.where("cities.name =?", params[:city]) if params[:city]
query = query.where("neighborhoods.name =?", params[:hood]) if params[:hood]
query = query.where("states.name =?", params[:state]) if params[:state]

json = query.map { |hood|
  {"state" => hood.state_name, "city" => hood.city_name, "neighborhood" => hood.name}
}.to_json
```

(untested, but I'm pretty sure that's close)

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I suppose the part that interests me most is how I could organize the queries via AR.  If I do use Arel/AR then I've got somewhat of a mess in terms of keeping things relatively efficient and also understandable from a maintenance perspective, unless there's some trick I'm missing...